# How to see diff between a committed file and edited file in Git ?

Tags: git, github

I have a file example.txt which I have committed with

```
git commit -m "added example"
```

now I edited this file and want to see the difference ? how can I see it ?

Comment: `man git diff` would have answered this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `$git diff example.txt`

Comment: Might want to use `git diff HEAD example.txt` instead, as it will only show changes between working copy and index otherwise.